# sameElements and "==" returning not equal althought the DataFrames are equal

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, scalatest

I'm trying to compare if two DataFrames have the same elements, and although the only row that both dataframes have are identical, it returns "not equal"

DFa it's retrieved using a listBuffer.toDF, DFb it's retrieved reading a csv file.

```
//Things I´ve tried
assert(DFa.collect().head === DFb.collect().head)
//Returns -> [111,222,333] did not equal [111,222,333]

assert(DFa.collect() sameElements DFb.collect())
//Returns -> scala.this.Predef.refArrayOps[org.apache.spark.sql.Row](DFa.collect()).sameElements[org.apache.spark.sql.Row](scala.this.Predef.wrapRefArray[org.apache.spark.sql.Row](DFb.collect())) was false

assert(DFa.collect().toList sameElements DFb.collect().toList)
//Returns ->  scala.this.Predef.refArrayOps[org.apache.spark.sql.Row](DFa.collect()).toList.sameElements[org.apache.spark.sql.Row](scala.this.Predef.refArrayOps[org.apache.spark.sql.Row](DFb.collect()).toList) was false

//Tried with toSeq as well, and with ".deep" using "==" and same errors
```

I don't get what's wrong, contents are the same, they are the same type and lenght on all the examples, except the collect one where on DFa I get "refArrayOps" and DFb I get "wrapRefArray"

The only workaround I came up with was:

```
val List1= new ListBuffer[String]
val List2= new ListBuffer[String]
DFa.foreach(row => List1+= row.toString)
DFb.foreach(row => List2 += row.toString)
assert(List1 == List2)
```

But I don't think is the best solution, and also I have another test which does the same "sameElements" and runs successfully.

Comment: Are the schemas equal? `DFa.schema === DFb.schema`

Comment: Are these object you compare having `equals` method overridden? Because on JVM by default you compare references. And I think since on Spark everything can be distributed you cannot check such things without being costly, so you are encouraged to do it consciously.

Comment: @ollik1 you push me onto the right track, that was the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

@olik1 push me onto the right track, they did not have the same schema, that was the issue, after tweaking the code it worked.